# Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables `dbo.tbRank` and `dbo.tbStaff`

- In `dbo.Rank` I have columns `RankID` and `RankName`
- In `dbo.Staff` I have columns `StaffID, StaffSNo, StaffRankID, StaffName, StaffGender`

How do I get `RankID` in `tbStaff` as `RankName` as in `tbRank`?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my stored procedure for `tbStaff`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectStaff]
    @sno as varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if @sno = ''
        begin
            select 
                StaffID, StaffSNo as 'Staff Service No.', StaffRankID,
                StaffName as 'Name', 
                case StaffGender 
                   when 'f' then 'female' when 'm' then 'male' 
                end as 'Gender' 
            from tbStaff
        end
    else 
    begin
      select 
         StaffID, StaffSNo, StaffRankID, StaffName, StaffGender 
         from tbStaff 
         where StaffSNo = @sno 
    end
END
```

Comment: Join your tbrank and tbstaff table by rankid and staffrankid  from tbrank and tbstaff and then you can get the rankname from tbrank

Answer (score 0):

use left join or inner join as per your needs.

```
select 
                a.StaffID, a.StaffSNo as 'Staff Service No.', a.StaffRankID,
                a.StaffName as 'Name', 
                case a.StaffGender 
                   when 'f' then 'female' when 'm' then 'male' 
                end as 'Gender' , b.RankName
            from tbStaff a
left outer join Rank b on b.RankID  = a.StaffRankID
```

Answer (score 0):

try below query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectStaff]
    @sno AS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@sno)) = ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            tST.StaffID,
            tST.StaffSNo AS 'Staff Service No.',
            tST.StaffRankID,
            tRK.RankName,
            tST.StaffName AS 'Name', 
            CASE tST.StaffGender 
               WHEN 'f' THEN 'female' WHEN 'm' THEN 'male'
            END AS Gender
        FROM tbStaff tST
        LEFT JOIN tbRank tRK ON tRK.RankID = tST.StaffRankID
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
         SELECT 
             tST.StaffID, tST.StaffSNo, tST.StaffRankID, tRK.RankName, tST.StaffName, tST.StaffGender
         FROM tbStaff tST
         LEFT JOIN tbRank tRK ON tRK.RankID = tST.StaffRankID
         WHERE tST.StaffSNo = @sno 
    END
END
```

Change the joins according to your needs LEFT or INNER

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. And it worked. Thank you for all those who helped. Your help was greatly appreciated.

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectStaff]
    @sno as varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    if @sno = ''
        begin
            select 
                tbStaff.StaffID, 
                tbStaff.StaffSNo as 'Service No.', 
                tbStaff.StaffRankID,
                tbRank.RankName as Rank,
                tbStaff.StaffName as 'Name', 
                case tbStaff.StaffGender 
                    when 'f' then 'female' 
                    when 'm' then 'male' 
                end as 'Gender'

```
        from tbStaff
        inner join tbRank on tbRank.RankID = tbStaff.StaffRankID
    end
else 
    begin
        select 
        tbStaff.StaffID,
        tbStaff.StaffSNo as 'Service No.',
        tbStaff.StaffRankID,
        tbRank.RankName as Rank,
        tbStaff.StaffName as Name,
        tbStaff.StaffGender from tbStaff 
        inner join tbRank on tbRank.RankID = tbStaff.StaffRankID
        where StaffSNo=@sno 
    end
```

END*emphasized text*